# PHP/SQL Juste a simple left join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table (ipvote)

[image]

Table (pictures)

[image]

What is the SQL query to retrieve all the images that were not voted for such ip '127 .0.0.1 '?

Thank you in advance,
Jeremie.

Comment: I don't think your requirement is clear - do you need to exclude all images that have a single vote from IP "127.0.0.1"? Or do you only need to exclude the votes that have come from that IP? Can you please share your query, if any, that you might have tried but did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM pictures
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ipvote WHERE idPicture = picutres.id AND ip = "127.0.0.1")
```

The picutre does not come through if...
- Many people voted, including "127.0.0.1"
- Just "127.0.0.1" voted

The picture does come through if...
- No-one voted
- One/Many people voted, but not "127.0.0.1"

Additionally, the picture only appears once, regardless of how many people voted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM pictures
LEFT JOIN ipvote pictures.id = ipvote.idPicture
WHERE ipvote.ip != "127.0.0.1"
```

Something like that.

Comment: I can't see the images, but this doesn't feel right.  If no-one voted, the ip field is NULL; this should be included in the results, but won't be as `NULL != "127.0.0.1"` will still fail.  Also, what if "127.0.0.1" voted, but so did other people?  The picutre will still come through because of the other people's votes...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `pictures` `p`
LEFT JOIN `ipvote` `iv`
ON `p`.`id` = `iv`.`idPicture` AND `iv`.`ip` != '127.0.0.1';
```

@Dems is right, check the comments.

Comment: Even if there is a record where "127.0.0.1" voted for a picture, the LEFT JOIN ensure that the picture will still be included in the results.  Every picutre will alwayas be included...

Comment: I don't understand your request !

Comment: @Dems: Nope, this query will exclude all the pictures which have an IP `127.0.0.1`. It will include those which do not have an IP entry though, that's a different.

Comment: If a picture has a vote from "127.0.0.1", the `!=` will prevent the record in `ipvote` from joining to the `picture` table.  As it is a LEFT JOIN, however, the record from `picture` will still be included in the results.  As formed, the LEFT JOIN will never exclude any record from `picture`.  Instead, it will only prevent votes from "127.0.0.1" being shown.

Answer (score 0):

select id from pictures p
where id not in 
(select idpicture as id from ipvote
where ip='127.0.0.1')